# Varnish - Seeing backend_busy without max_connection

Tags: varnish

Using Varnish 3.0.4, we're seeing a lot of backend_busy, but we do not have set max_connection setting in any of our backends.

I'm trying to find out why because it seems some clients requests get aborted.

what could cause a backend_busy ?

thanks for any tips

here's my varnishstat -1

```
client_conn                  0         0.00 Client connections accepted
client_drop                  0         0.00 Connection dropped, no sess/wrk
client_req                   0         0.00 Client requests received
cache_hit                    0         0.00 Cache hits
cache_hitpass                0         0.00 Cache hits for pass
cache_miss                   0         0.00 Cache misses
backend_conn                 0         0.00 Backend conn. success
backend_unhealthy            0         0.00 Backend conn. not attempted
backend_busy            386013         8.38 Backend conn. too many
backend_fail                 0         0.00 Backend conn. failures
backend_reuse          1140751        24.77 Backend conn. reuses
backend_toolate         292966         6.36 Backend conn. was closed
backend_recycle          31329         0.68 Backend conn. recycles
backend_retry           364845         7.92 Backend conn. retry
fetch_head               93857         2.04 Fetch head
fetch_length                 0         0.00 Fetch with Length
fetch_chunked                0         0.00 Fetch chunked
fetch_eof                 1007         0.02 Fetch EOF
fetch_bad               766163        16.63 Fetch had bad headers
fetch_close              16152         0.35 Fetch wanted close
fetch_oldhttp           783263        17.00 Fetch pre HTTP/1.1 closed
fetch_zero               14372         0.31 Fetch zero len
fetch_failed                83         0.00 Fetch failed
fetch_1xx               792868        17.21 Fetch no body (1xx)
fetch_204                28600         0.62 Fetch no body (204)
fetch_304                    0         0.00 Fetch no body (304)
n_sess_mem                   0          .   N struct sess_mem
n_sess                     849          .   N struct sess
n_object                     0          .   N struct object
n_vampireobject              0          .   N unresurrected objects
n_objectcore                 0          .   N struct objectcore
n_objecthead                 0          .   N struct objecthead
n_waitinglist                0          .   N struct waitinglist
n_vbc                      674          .   N struct vbc
n_wrk                     1819          .   N worker threads
n_wrk_create               155         0.00 N worker threads created
n_wrk_failed            237296         5.15 N worker threads not created
n_wrk_max                    0         0.00 N worker threads limited
n_wrk_lqueue            237394         5.15 work request queue length
n_wrk_queued            237937         5.17 N queued work requests
n_wrk_drop                 128         0.00 N dropped work requests
n_backend                   96          .   N backends
n_expired                  135          .   N expired objects
n_lru_nuked               7710          .   N LRU nuked objects
n_lru_moved                  0          .   N LRU moved objects
losthdr                      0         0.00 HTTP header overflows
n_objsendfile                0         0.00 Objects sent with sendfile
n_objwrite               49182         1.07 Objects sent with write
n_objoverflow                0         0.00 Objects overflowing workspace
s_sess                      25         0.00 Total Sessions
s_req                   104479         2.27 Total Requests
s_pipe                       0         0.00 Total pipe
s_pass                  205233         4.46 Total pass
s_fetch                      0         0.00 Total fetch
s_hdrbytes                   0         0.00 Total header bytes
s_bodybytes            1093243        23.73 Total body bytes
sess_closed                  0         0.00 Session Closed
sess_pipeline           385979         8.38 Session Pipeline
sess_readahead         1140751        24.77 Session Read Ahead
sess_linger                758         0.02 Session Linger
sess_herd               482049        10.46 Session herd
shm_records             823074        17.87 SHM records
shm_writes           470696378     10218.54 SHM writes
shm_flushes        10834209993    235204.18 SHM flushes due to overflow
shm_cont                167868         3.64 SHM MTX contention
shm_cycles                  19         0.00 SHM cycles through buffer
sms_nreq                    18         0.00 SMS allocator requests
sms_nobj               1092005          .   SMS outstanding allocations
sms_nbytes              635568          .   SMS outstanding bytes
sms_balloc            85592445          .   SMS bytes allocated
sms_bfree              5323477          .   SMS bytes freed
backend_req                 42         0.00 Backend requests made
n_vcl                    44231         0.96 N vcl total
n_vcl_avail                 37         0.00 N vcl available
n_vcl_discard            23820         0.52 N vcl discarded
n_ban                        0          .   N total active bans
n_ban_add                    0         0.00 N new bans added
n_ban_retire        2136286212     46377.49 N old bans deleted
n_ban_obj_test      2136286212     46377.49 N objects tested
n_ban_re_test           857240        18.61 N regexps tested against
n_ban_dups                   1         0.00 N duplicate bans removed
hcb_nolock                   1         0.00 HCB Lookups without lock
hcb_lock                     0         0.00 HCB Lookups with lock
hcb_insert               28435         0.62 HCB Inserts
esi_errors               14884         0.32 ESI parse errors (unlock)
esi_warnings            246931         5.36 ESI parse warnings (unlock)
accept_fail             218496         4.74 Accept failures
client_drop_late       5603745       121.65 Connection dropped late
uptime             29071691616    631128.92 Client uptime
dir_dns_lookups          46063         1.00 DNS director lookups
dir_dns_failed          685875        14.89 DNS director failed lookups
dir_dns_hit             356122         7.73 DNS director cached lookups hit
dir_dns_cache_full      355962         7.73 DNS director full dnscache
vmods                        0          .   Loaded VMODs
n_gzip                       0         0.00 Gzip operations
n_gunzip                     0         0.00 Gunzip operations
LCK.sms.creat                0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.sms.destroy              0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.sms.locks                0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.sms.colls                0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.smp.creat                0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.smp.destroy              0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.smp.locks                0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.smp.colls                0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.sma.creat                0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.sma.destroy              0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.sma.locks                0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.sma.colls                0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.smf.creat                0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.smf.destroy              0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.smf.locks                0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.smf.colls                0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.hsl.creat                0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.hsl.destroy              0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.hsl.locks                0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.hsl.colls                0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.hcb.creat                0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.hcb.destroy              0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.hcb.locks                0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.hcb.colls                0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.hcl.creat                0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.hcl.destroy              0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.hcl.locks                0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.hcl.colls                0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.vcl.creat                0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.vcl.destroy              0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.vcl.locks                0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.vcl.colls                0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.stat.creat               0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.stat.destroy             0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.stat.locks               0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.stat.colls               0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.sessmem.creat            0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.sessmem.destroy            0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.sessmem.locks              0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.sessmem.colls              0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.wstat.creat                0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.wstat.destroy              0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.wstat.locks                0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.wstat.colls                0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.herder.creat               0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.herder.destroy             0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.herder.locks               0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.herder.colls               0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.wq.creat                   0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.wq.destroy                 0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.wq.locks                   0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.wq.colls                   0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.objhdr.creat               0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.objhdr.destroy             0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.objhdr.locks               0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.objhdr.colls               0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.exp.creat                  0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.exp.destroy                0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.exp.locks                  0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.exp.colls                  0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.lru.creat                  0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.lru.destroy                0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.lru.locks                  0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.lru.colls                  0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.cli.creat                  0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.cli.destroy                0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.cli.locks                  0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.cli.colls                  0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.ban.creat                  0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.ban.destroy                0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.ban.locks                  0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.ban.colls                  0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.vbp.creat                  0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.vbp.destroy                0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.vbp.locks                  0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.vbp.colls                  0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.vbe.creat                  0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.vbe.destroy                0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.vbe.locks                  0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.vbe.colls                  0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.backend.creat              0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.backend.destroy            0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.backend.locks              0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.backend.colls              0         0.00 Collisions
SMA.s0.c_req                   0         0.00 Allocator requests
SMA.s0.c_fail                  0         0.00 Allocator failures
SMA.s0.c_bytes                 0         0.00 Bytes allocated
SMA.s0.c_freed                 0         0.00 Bytes freed
SMA.s0.g_alloc                 0          .   Allocations outstanding
SMA.s0.g_bytes                 0          .   Bytes outstanding
SMA.s0.g_space                 0          .   Bytes available
SMA.Transient.c_req            0         0.00 Allocator requests
SMA.Transient.c_fail           0         0.00 Allocator failures
SMA.Transient.c_bytes            0         0.00 Bytes allocated
SMA.Transient.c_freed            0         0.00 Bytes freed
SMA.Transient.g_alloc            0          .   Allocations outstanding
SMA.Transient.g_bytes            0          .   Bytes outstanding
SMA.Transient.g_space            0          .   Bytes available
VBE.default(127.0.0.1,,8080).vcls            0          .   VCL references
VBE.default(127.0.0.1,,8080).happy           0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.wiki(127.0.0.1,,8081).vcls               0          .   VCL references
VBE.wiki(127.0.0.1,,8081).happy              0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.tiles(127.0.0.1,,9090).vcls              0          .   VCL references
VBE.tiles(127.0.0.1,,9090).happy             0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.geoserver(127.0.0.1,,43074).vcls            0          .   VCL references
VBE.geoserver(127.0.0.1,,43074).happy           0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.iconserver(127.0.0.1,,43077).vcls           0          .   VCL references
VBE.iconserver(127.0.0.1,,43077).happy            0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.uploadserver(127.0.0.1,,43079).vcls           0          .   VCL references
VBE.uploadserver(127.0.0.1,,43079).happy            0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.graphserver(127.0.0.1,,43080).vcls              0          .   VCL references
VBE.graphserver(127.0.0.1,,43080).happy             0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.kmlserver(127.0.0.1,,43082).vcls                0          .   VCL references
VBE.kmlserver(127.0.0.1,,43082).happy               0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.feedbackserver(127.0.0.1,,43085).vcls           0          .   VCL references
VBE.feedbackserver(127.0.0.1,,43085).happy            0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.weatherserver(127.0.0.1,,43086).vcls              0          .   VCL references
VBE.weatherserver(127.0.0.1,,43086).happy             0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.analyticsserver(127.0.0.1,,43087).vcls            0          .   VCL references
VBE.analyticsserver(127.0.0.1,,43087).happy           0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.chartserver(127.0.0.1,,43088).vcls                0          .   VCL references
VBE.chartserver(127.0.0.1,,43088).happy               0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.watcher(127.0.0.1,,8090).vcls                     0          .   VCL references
VBE.watcher(127.0.0.1,,8090).happy                    0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.render(127.0.0.1,,8040).vcls                      0          .   VCL references
VBE.render(127.0.0.1,,8040).happy                     0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.route(127.0.0.1,,43073).vcls                      0          .   VCL references
VBE.route(127.0.0.1,,43073).happy                     0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.osmsync(127.0.0.1,,9010).vcls                     0          .   VCL references
VBE.osmsync(127.0.0.1,,9010).happy                    0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.search(127.0.0.1,,8100).vcls                      0          .   VCL references
VBE.search(127.0.0.1,,8100).happy                     0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.indexserver(127.0.0.1,,8101).vcls                 0          .   VCL references
VBE.indexserver(127.0.0.1,,8101).happy                0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.rewriteproxy(127.0.0.1,,9030).vcls                0          .   VCL references
VBE.rewriteproxy(127.0.0.1,,9030).happy               0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.pomplo(127.0.0.1,,9081).vcls                      0          .   VCL references
VBE.pomplo(127.0.0.1,,9081).happy                     0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.admin(127.0.0.1,,9000).vcls                       0          .   VCL references
VBE.admin(127.0.0.1,,9000).happy                      0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.graphite(127.0.0.1,,7070).vcls                    0          .   VCL references
VBE.graphite(127.0.0.1,,7070).happy                   0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.notificationserver(127.0.0.1,,8070).vcls            0          .   VCL references
VBE.notificationserver(127.0.0.1,,8070).happy           0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.orient(127.0.0.1,,2480).vcls                        0          .   VCL references
VBE.orient(127.0.0.1,,2480).happy                       0          .   Happy health probes
VBE.geoip(127.0.0.1,,43930).vcls                        0          .   VCL references
VBE.geoip(127.0.0.1,,43930).happy                       0          .   Happy health probes
```

here's my vcl (included in default.vcl)
    import std;

```
acl internal {
    "localhost";
    "192.168.0.0"/16;
    "10.0.0.0"/8;
}

probe status {
    .url = "/status.json";
    .timeout = 100 ms;
    .interval = 1s;
    .threshold = 1;
}

probe rootCheck {
    .url = "/";
    .timeout = 100 ms;
    .interval = 1s;
    .threshold = 1;
}

backend tiles {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "9090";
    .probe = {
        .url = "/serverInfo.json";
        .timeout = 100 ms;
        .interval = 1s;
        .threshold = 1;
    }
}

backend geoserver {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "43074";
    .probe = rootCheck;
}

backend iconserver {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "43077";
    .probe = rootCheck;
}

backend uploadserver {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "43079";
    .probe = rootCheck;
}

backend graphserver {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "43080";
    .probe = rootCheck;
}

backend kmlserver {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "43082";
    .probe = rootCheck;
}

backend weatherserver {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "43086";
    .probe = {
        .url = "/status";
        .timeout = 100 ms;
        .interval = 1s;
        .threshold = 1;
    }
}

backend analyticsserver {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "43087";
    .probe = status;
}

backend chartserver {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "43088";
    .probe = status;
}

backend watcher {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8090";
    .probe = {
        .url = "/test";
        .timeout = 100 ms;
        .interval = 1s;
        .threshold = 1;
    }
}

backend route {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "43073";
    .probe = status;
}

backend osmsync {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "9010";
    .probe = {
        .url = "/state.json";
        .timeout = 100 ms;
        .interval = 1s;
        .threshold = 1;
    }
}

backend search {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8100";
    .probe = status;
}

backend indexserver {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8101";
    .probe = rootCheck;
}

backend rewriteproxy {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "9030";
    .probe = rootCheck;
}

backend webserver {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "9081";
    .probe = rootCheck;
}

backend admin {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "9000";
    .probe = rootCheck;
}

backend graphite {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "7070";
    .probe = rootCheck;
}

backend notificationserver {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8070";
    .probe = status;
}

backend orient {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "2480";
}

backend geoip {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "43930";
    .probe = status;
}

sub allow_only_internal {
    if (!client.ip ~ internal) {
        error 405 "Not allowed.";
    }
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "\.(png|gif|jpg|swf|css|js|bis|apk|plist|ipa|woff|svg|eot|ttf|json)(\?.*|)$") {
         unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    if (req.url ~ "^/admin") {
        call allow_only_internal;
    }

    if( req.http.host ~ "^tile" ) {
        unset req.http.cookie;
        set req.http.host = "tiles";
        set req.backend = tiles;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^data" ) {
        set req.backend = geoserver;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^icon" ) {
        unset req.http.cookie;
        set req.backend = iconserver;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^upload" ) {
        set req.backend = uploadserver;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^graphite" ) { // must be before graph
        if( req.url !~ "^/render" ) { //allow render API anywhere
            call allow_only_internal;
        }
        set req.backend = graphite;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^graph" ) {
        set req.backend = graphserver;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^kml" ) {
        set req.backend = kmlserver;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^notification" ) {
        set req.backend = notificationserver;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^osmsync" ) {
        set req.backend = osmsync;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^watcher" ) {
        set req.backend = watcher;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^route" ) {
        set req.backend = route;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^search" ) {
        set req.backend = search;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^index" ) {
        call allow_only_internal;
        set req.backend = indexserver;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^weather" ) {
        set req.backend = weatherserver;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^analytics" ) {
        set req.backend = analyticsserver;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^chart" ) {
        set req.backend = chartserver;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^geoip" ) {
        set req.backend = geoip;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^rewriteproxy" || req.http.host ~ "^showroom" ) {
        set req.backend = rewriteproxy;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^admin" ) {
        call allow_only_internal;
        set req.backend = admin;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^orient" ) {
        call allow_only_internal;
        set req.backend = orient;
    }
    //url matching is at the bottom to avoid confusion
    else if( req.url ~ "^/query" ) {
        set req.backend = geoserver;
    } else if( req.url ~ "^/data/" ) {
        set req.url = regsub( req.url, "^/data(/.*)", "\1" );
        set req.backend = geoserver;
    }  else if( req.url ~ "^/icon/" ) {
        set req.url = regsub( req.url, "^/icon(/.*)", "\1" );
        set req.backend = iconserver;
    } else if( req.url ~ "^/graph/" ) {
        set req.url = regsub( req.url, "^/graph(/.*)", "\1" );
        set req.backend = graphserver;
    } else if( req.http.host ~ "^(www\.|static|map)" ) {
        set req.backend = webserver;
    } else {
        // todo: handle HTTPS with req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto
        // redirect dev and demo to avoid dead links for old urls
        error 750 regsub(req.http.host, "^(w+\.|dev\.|demo\.)?", "http://www.") + req.url;
    }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.Location ~ ".*:8080.*") {
        set resp.http.Location = regsub(resp.http.Location, ":[0-9]+", "");
    }
    if (req.backend == graphite) {
        set resp.http.Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*";
        set resp.http.Access-Control-Allow-Methods = "GET, OPTIONS";
        set resp.http.Access-Control-Allow-Headers = "origin, authorization, accept";
    }

    unset resp.http.x-url;
    unset resp.http.x-host;
    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_fetch {
    if (req.url ~ "\.(png|gif|jpg|swf|css|js|bis|apk|plist|ipa|woff|svg|eot|ttf|json)(\?.*|)$") {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

    if( beresp.http.content-type ~ "application/json"
     || beresp.http.content-type ~ "application/javascript"
     || (beresp.http.content-type ~ "application/octet-stream" && req.url ~ "\.bis$")
     || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text/javascript"
     || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text/plain"
     || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text/html"
     || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text/css" ) {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    //allow ban lurker to work. https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/Cache_invalidation.html#smart-bans
    set beresp.http.x-url = req.url;
    set beresp.http.x-host = req.http.host;
}

sub vcl_pipe {
  if (req.http.upgrade) {
    set bereq.http.upgrade = req.http.upgrade;
  }
}

sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.http.Upgrade ~ "(?i)websocket") {
    return (pipe);
  }
}

sub vcl_error {
    if (obj.status == 750) {
        set obj.http.Location = obj.response;
        set obj.status = 302;
        return (deliver);
    }
    set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    set obj.http.Retry-After = "3";
    if( req.http.host ~ "^map" ) {
        synthetic regsuball(regsuball(std.fileread("/etc/varnish/error_map.html"), "\$obj\.status\$", obj.status), "\$obj\.response\$", obj.response);
    } else {
        synthetic regsuball(regsuball(std.fileread("/etc/varnish/error.html"), "\$obj\.status\$", obj.status), "\$obj\.response\$", obj.response);
    }
    return (deliver);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That would normally be because none of your backends in the requested director are healthy at the time.

None of your servers seems to be used in your VCL nor have any health probes. So it's hard to know why exactly this happens. You should also really be using the backends you define and do health checks on them.

When you see something more like the following for all backends your varnishstat is least giving you some useful information:

```
VBE.wiki(127.0.0.1,,8081).vcls               1          
VBE.wiki(127.0.0.1,,8081).happy          18446744073709551615
```

You can also check current status and short history by "debug.health" in your varnishadm console.

Comment: I don't have any health probe at the moment but all backends are used in the vcl (varnish redirects properly and caches result properly, most of the time). I'll try adding health probes and report back.

Comment: I've added health probes to most backends, and they show up healthy in debug.health , but the values in varnishstat -1 are still 0. I'm looking into it.

Comment: If you need help with that you'd better show your vcl file(s).

Comment: vcl added. The values in varnishstat -1 are still 0. I still can't understand why varnish does not consider my rules for those stats

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your *libvarnishapi* lib — this helped me (ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install libvarnishapi1
```

and reboot.

If you are using a wrong version (mine was *libvarnishapi-dev*), you don't get varnishstat working properly.

Comment: I already have libvarnishapi1, but thanks for the idea !
We're not seeing those errors as frequently but i have no idea why :/

Comment: This helped with my varnishstats being all wrong. Why it isn't a dependency I don't know. Thing is was working in varnish 3.02 without this, but upgrade to 5 and it went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

By default when `backend_busy` is incremented, that means the client receives a 5xx error response. However by using VCL ([Varnish Configuration Language](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCL)), it seems that you can apparently configure Varnish to recover from a "busy backend" by using a different backend, or by serving an outdated or synthetic response.
([Source](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-monitor-varnish/))

Note: I think `backend_busy` is different from `backend_unhealthy`.
Actually Varnish periodically pings the backend to make sure it is still up and responsive. If it doesn’t receive a 200 response quickly enough, the backend is marked as **unhealthy** and every new request to it increments `backend_unhealthy`  until the backend recovers and sends a timely 200 response.